# Reading contents after splitting

Tags: java, split

My problem is that I have a code and I have a problem of fixing the "Cannot find symbol" error. Here's the code.

```
public static void writer() throws IOException {
    FileReader in = null;
    FileWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        in = new FileReader("Student.txt");
        out = new FileWriter("StudentAvg.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(in);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
        String[] line = new String[28];
        line = in.split("\t");
```

The error is pointed on the splitting process. Is there a problem with my variables?

Comment: There's no method `split` in [`java.io.FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) class. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you haven't read any lines.

```
br = new BufferedReader(in);
bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
String[] line = new String[28];
line = in.split("\t"); // <-- this is your input file reader.
```

I think you wanted

```
br = new BufferedReader(in);
bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
String fromFile;
while ((fromFile = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] line = fromFile.split("\t");
```

You might also use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and something like

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(//
        new FileReader("Student.txt"));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(//
                new FileWriter("StudentAvg.txt"))) {
    String fromFile;
    while ((fromFile = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] line = fromFile.split("\t");
    }
}
```